# Time Complexity of the Number of Islands question

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, breadth-first-search

I am trying to solve the following problem: given a grid of 0s and 1s, find the number of “islands” of 1s, where an “island” is a region of 1s reachable from one another by moving up, down, left, or right.

What is the time complexity of the code given below? I think it should be O(rcn), where n is the maximum island size. However, on Geeks for Geeks, they say the time complexity is O(V+E).

```
void bfs(int r, int c, vector < vector < char >> & grid) {
  queue < pair < int, int >> q;
  int row[4] = {-1,0,1,0};
  int col[4] = {0,1,0,-1};
  q.push(make_pair(r, c));
  while (!q.empty()) {
    pair < int, int > p = q.front();
    int x = p.first;
    int y = p.second;
    q.pop();

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      if (x + row[i] < grid.size() && y + col[i] < grid[0].size() && x + row[i] >= 0 && y + col[i] >= 0 && grid[x + row[i]][y + col[i]] == '1') {
        q.push(make_pair(x + row[i], y + col[i]));
        grid[x + row[i]][y + col[i]] = '0';
      }
    }
  }
}
int numIslands(vector < vector < char >> & grid) {
  int count = 0;
  int r = grid.size();
  if (r == 0)
    return count;
  int c = grid[0].size();
  for (int i = 0; i < r; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < c; j++) {
      if (grid[i][j] == '1') {
        bfs(i, j, grid);
        count++;
      }
    }
  }
  return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let’s start with your bound of O(rcn), where

- r is the number of rows,
- c is the number of columns, and
- n is the maximum island size.

I believe you obtained this bound in the following way:

1. There are rc total positions in the grid.
2. For each position, we may need to call the bfs function on that position.
3. The bfs function does O(n) work.
4. Thus the total work is O(rcn).

This line of reasoning is correct, but it will significantly overcount the amount of work being done. To see this, let’s consider an extreme case. Suppose the entire grid is filled with 1s. Then the very first call to bfs will do a large amount of work, but since it changes all the 1s to 0s, none of the future bfs calls will do any significant amount of work. More specifically, the first call to bfs will do O(rc) work as it visits every position in the grid, and all future bfs calls will only take time O(1). This makes the total amount of work O(rc), much lower than the hound of O(rcn).

In fact, we can bound the amount of work done in any possible input world at O(rc). Here’s the line of reasoning for doing this. If we leave out the calls to bfs, we do a baseline amount of work equal to O(rc) because we visit each grid location once. Furthermore, across all calls to bfs, each grid location can change from 1 to 0 once, and the work done by the bfs function depends purely on how many 1s change to 0s. There are at most rc 1s in the grid, and so the total work changing all those 1s to 0s is O(rc). Thus the baseline work is O(rc), and on top of that the work for all calls to bfs is at most O(rc), so we do O(rc) total work.

Now, when you looked this up online, you got a bound of O(V + E). That bound is also correct, but to interpret what it means we need to see what V and E are. In the context of graph search algorithms like BFS, the term V refers to the number of positions (nodes, in graph speak) and E refers to the number of links between positions (edges, in graph speak). In your case, the number of nodes V is rc: there’s one node per grid cell. As for edges, there is one edge between each pair of adjacent 1 values. Each node will therefore have at most 4 edges touching it (up/down/left/right), so the number of edges is at most 4rc. This means the O(V + E) bound is O(rc + 4rc) = O(5rc) = O(rc), with the 5 getting munch munched by the fact that big-O notation ignores constant factors. This matches the O(rc) we got above, which means this is another perfectly good way to arrive at the result. :-)